# Can I use the EPL-licensed library (Paho) for a proprietary project and NOT disclose the source code of the project?

Tags: licensing, commercial, linked-libraries, dependencies, epl

Can I use the [Eclipse Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) library (licensed under [EPL](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html)) for a proprietary  project and NOT disclose the whole source code of that project? I'm not going to make any changes to Paho code, I just want to use it as a library in an Android app. Are there precedents? I could not find the exact answer on the Internet.

Comment: Please link to a version of the license text in English: [Eclipse Public License - v 1.0](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html)

Comment: @Brandin thank you, that was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a letter to the Eclipse Foundation. The consultant pointed me to [point 5 in their FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/faq.php#epl-derivative). My case falls under the term "linking". He warned that he isn't a lawyer, but offered the following short answer:

> The Eclipse Foundation does not consider linking with EPL content to be a derivative work and so you are not required to disclose your source code.

Comment: IANAL - You are not required to disclose your proprietary source code. Though you must fulfil the EPL license obligations.